# Django Admin keeps returning 504 timeout ( nginx +uWSGI )

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, uwsgi, systemd

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.nameOfSite.id nameOfSite.id;

    access_log  off;
    error_log  /var/www/log_nginx/error.log;   
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    client_header_timeout 180s;
    client_body_timeout 180s;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    proxy_connect_timeout   120s;
    proxy_send_timeout      180s;
    proxy_read_timeout      180s;
    send_timeout            600s;

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /static {    
        alias /var/www/django/static;    
    }

    location /media {    
       alias /var/www/django/media;    
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 500;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 500;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/var/www/uwsgi_texas.sock;
    }

}
```

This is my uWSGI ini file in /var/www/texas_uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/www/uwsgi_texas.sock
chdir = /var/www/django/
wsgi-file = /var/www/django/django/wsgi.py
processes = 8
threads = 1
master = true
harakiri = 900
chmod-socket = 777
vacuum = true
```

This is my service file in /etc/systemd/system/texas.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=TEXAS
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/texas_uwsgi.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is when i enter the Django admin for one Model object that have a lot of inline objects and fields, it keeps returning 504 timeout because it takes more than 60 seconds to process. I checked my NGINX, uWSGI configurations, i cannot find the solution on how to increase this "60 seconds timeout". The rest of the pages works fine.

In my nginx configuration, i already tried:

```
proxy_connect_timeout   120s;
proxy_send_timeout      180s;
proxy_read_timeout      180s;
send_timeout            600s;
uwsgi_read_timeout 500;
uwsgi_send_timeout 500;
```

This is the result when i try to open that Model Admin page:

[image: the error]

Comment: Do all the admin pages result in this problem?

Comment: no, only one Model's admin called Product shows that problem, because it has around 10 inlines models inside it, and it has a lot of properties.

Comment: it only shows that if it has a lot of data, which leads to more than 60 seconds to process & return to the browser. I keep getting 504 timeout for that model, The rest of the admin has no problem, and it works in my localhost machine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use raw_id fields(for the inline models) for loading the admin wherever necessary.

Refer: [Django Admin raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

by doing so you can bypass the 504 error

Comment: i can't, the admin would be unusable, it can work for some fields, but if i used it on the inline, it would be hard to use for my admins

Comment: I dont think it will become unusable, the only change is that it will be a text box instead of select, also you will have a search option.

Comment: well making it raw_id_fields does works, now it does not show the error, but i hope there's a better solution. I think this has something to do with "max_body_size" the server can send to the user. But the errors i received was 504